# Hibernate JNDI lookup for WebLogic is throwing unable to resolve

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, jndi, weblogic12c

I have configured a datasource configured on Oracle Weblogic 12.1.3 and trying to lookup this datasource in a Spring MVC application.

```
// Weblogic configuration
Datasource Name in weblogic : Admin Data Source
JNDI Name : bsh/AdminDS
```

```
// Spring MVC Configuration
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSourceUsingJndi() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("bsh/AdminDS"); // 1st way
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSourceUsingJndi());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, hibernateDialect);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, showSql);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.FORMAT_SQL, formatSql);
        return properties;
    }
```

I am getting the below stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'bsh.AdminDS'. Resolved 'bsh'; remaining name 'AdminDS'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1180)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:270)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:187)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:210)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:224)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:156)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:156)
    at com.bsh.config.WebConfig.getDataSourceUsingJndi(WebConfig.java:68)
```

I tried different ways to lookup - 2nd way

```
    public DataSource getDataSourceUsingJndi() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndiLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        jndiLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return jndiLookup.getDataSource("bsh/AdminDS");
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: Are you using a multi tenancy server? If so check your resource groups/templates for the partition(s).

Comment: @ChadNC I am not using a multi tenancy server. There is only 1 server with the above datasource configured. The JNDI lookup works intermittently with WebLogic 12.2.1, but never worked with 12.1.3

Comment: Have you tried looking up the JNDI name like so. java:comp/env/bsh/AdminDS. Just a side note but typically a JDBC resource has a JNDI name in this format jdbc/AdminDS.

Comment: I upgraded my web logic to 12.2.1.3 and it did the trick. The jndi name was in the right format - xyz/jndiname. Thanks @ChadNC